# Validating user input against a range using tool validator in arcpy script?

Tags: arcpy, tool-validation

I have a script that takes user input. For the "Project ID" input field, the user can only enter a 4 character ID. The ID may include letters and numbers, but is typically a 4-digit number. I'm trying to use the script's ToolValidator to make sure the user enters only 4 characters before the script will run. I am using the correct parameter index #.

I've tried several different code variations, but this is an example of my last attempt. With the following code, no matter what value I enter, the "Project ID" field returns blank with no error message.

Also, the "Project ID" parameter is a STRING data type in the event we encounter a project ID that contains a letter and is a required field. I would normally just check the length of the input, but couldn't find a len() method to use. I figured I could test if the entry was less/greater than 10000 to obtain the 4 digit restriction.

How should I proceed?

```
import arcpy
class ToolValidator(object):
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()

  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    if self.params[6].altered and not self.params[6].hasBeenValidated:
      if self.params[6].value >= '10000':
        self.params[6].value = ""
    return

  def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    if self.params[6].value >= '10000':
      self.params[6].setErrorMessage ("Project number can only have 4 positive digits. Please enter a 4-digit project number.")
    else:
      self.params[6].clearMessage()
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code you need in `updateMessages()` :

It would check if an alpha numeric code is 4 characters long and a numeric code must not be greater than 9999. The key function is `isdigit()` this allows you to split off the logic for numeric and alphanumeric codes.

```py
  def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    if self.params[0].altered:
        theID = self.params[0].value # could be something like ab12 or 3330
        if theID.isdigit():
            # Ensure number (assumed integer) is not greater than 9999
            num = int(theID)
            if num >= 10000:
                self.params[0].setErrorMessage("Project ID is invalid!")
            else:
                self.params[0].clearMessage()
        else:
            # Ensure alpha numeric ID is exactly 4 characters long
            if len(theID) != 4 :
                self.params[0].setErrorMessage("Project ID is invalid!")
            else:
                self.params[0].clearMessage()
    return
```

Comment: This worked for me. With the modification of one line of code to `if num < 1000 or num >= 10000:`, I was able to make sure an entered number was exactly 4 digits.